# Playing the game with Wingman RumblePad (OS X / Mac)

Tags: team-fortress-2, controllers, macos

I would like to know how I can connect my Logitech WingMan RumblePad to my Mac so I can play TF2 with it, using CoD-esque controls (Left Thumb = Move, Right Thumb = Aim). I have tried editing the `joystick.cfg` file, but that didn't seem to work — am I possibly missing something?

I have tried external applications like *USB Overdrive* (which works, but it flips the thumbsticks for me), *ControllerMate* (which doesn't let me control the mouse without registering), and *GamePad Companion* (which also requires registration). I would like to find a free alternative, if possible; any suggestions?

Comment: I would expect `joystick.cfg` to have no effect given that “[Gamepads, joysticks, and 360 controllers are currently not supported on Mac versions of Valve games.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6292-PQMG-6828)” (I was just researching this yesterday.) I look forward to seeing answers to this question.

Comment: @KevinReid I did find a solution with ControllerMate, but It doesn't allow me to map all of the buttons (for free), so I am still awaiting answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Enjoy](http://abstractable.net/enjoy/)  - a JoyToKey clone for mac

Comment: One issue: I don't see a way to bind to the mouse. I'll still check it out later today, though.